# Vertically bottom align a linear gradient

Tags: css

I have made a jsfiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/wLomyf65/

HTML:

```
<div class="skeleton-6euk0cm7tfi"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.skeleton-6euk0cm7tfi:empty {height: 100px; background-color: #ffffff; border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-image: linear-gradient( #676b6f 6px, transparent 0 );background-repeat: repeat-y;background-size: 88px 100px;background-position: left 0px bottom 0px;}
```

I wish to vertically bottom align the linear gradient (so that its in the bottom left corner).

I have used: `background-position: left 0px bottom 0px;` but this hasn't done it.

Comment: it's already at bottom left, you have set its height equal to the container height so bottom and top make no difference

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry I'm not understanding. If I change the background size from 88px 100px to 88px 6px then it's height goes 100% of the container.

Comment: It's going to '100% of the container' when the height is set at 6px because you have asked it to repeat. Could you describe (or give a picture) what you want it to look like? Do you want that gray stripe at the bottom of the white div?

Comment: @AHaworth yes that’s correct. I’d like the grey stripe on the bottom left of the white div please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight problem with the way you are setting things up is that the height of the element itself and the height of the background image (before you have sized it) are the same, and its drawing the gray for 6px from the top (the default direction for a linear-gradient) and the rest is transparent.

This snippet slightly simplifies what is going on.

It 'draws'a background image in the gray color, setting its width to 88% and its height to 6px and its position to bottom left. It sets it to not repeat on either axis.

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

.skeleton-6euk0cm7tfi:empty {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( #676b6f, #676b6f);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 88px 6px;
  background-position: left bottom;
}

<
```

```html
<div class="skeleton-6euk0cm7tfi"></div>
```